# HTML table output

Tags: html, html-table, xquery

I've got a XML file that contains this data:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
   <university>
    <lecture>
        <class>English</class>
        <hours>3</hours>
        <pupils>30</pupils>
    </lecture>
    <lecture>
        <class>Math</class>
        <hours>4</hours>
        <pupils>27</pupils
    </lecture>
    <lecture>
        <class>Science</class>
        <hours>2</hours>
        <pupils>25</pupils>
    </lecture>
   </university>
```

Is it possible if I can get an XQuery code that produces this output (below) for me?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>English class runs for 3 with 30 pupils</td>
    <td>Math class runs for 4 with 26 pupils</td>
    <td>Science class runs for 2 with 25 pupils</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** Below is my attempt:

```
let $classroom := doc("uni.xml")/university/lecture/class
let $hr := doc("uni.xml")/university/lecture/hours
let $pupl := doc("uni.xml")/university/lecture/pupils

<tr>
<table>

for $a in $classroom,
$b in $hr,
$c in $pupl

return <td>{$a} class runs for {$b} with {$c} pupils</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

I get an error saying I need to return a value, which I already did. If I take out the tr and table tags, it works, but gives me an endless loop result.

Comment: As posted, your XML input is not well-formed. XML requires single root element.. Also, have you tried something so far? Please share

Comment: @har07 : I've attempted it (see my edit), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to the updated XML, and a bit of your attempted XQuery style which using variables, I'd suggest something like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
{
    for $lecture in doc("uni.xml")/university/lecture
    let $class := $lecture/class/string()
    let $hours := $lecture/hours/string()
    let $pupils := $lecture/pupils/string()
    return 
        <td>{$class} class runs for {$hours} with {$pupils} pupils</td>
}
</tr>
</table>
```

Demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xquery/33e31b342098712e331285bda3010e0c

Basically, the query loop through common parent elements that contains all the needed information; the `lecture` elements. Then use simple relative XPath/XQuery to extract data from each `lecture` to produce the required output.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my post above with the corrections to the xml and my attempted code. Let me know what you think of the code.

Comment: @mrteeth Updated my answer accordingly. I honestly appreciate your attempt, but I think it isn't in the right direction (I mean the `for` construct), so above suggested a bit different approach to accomplish the task.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the correction. It works well. I was wondering why did you put let inside the for loop? Is it supposed to be more efficient?

Comment: That way, each variable value changes according to the value of `$lecture` in current `for` loop iteration..

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for the info.